# node-redis reports "EXEC without MULT"

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Error Output:

```
[Error: ERR EXEC without MULTI]
```

Nodejs Script:

```
client  = redis.createClient(REDIS_SOCK);

client.keys(['*'], function(err, keys) {
  client.multi();

  keys.forEach(function(key) {
      count = start;

      while(count <= end) {
          client.zrangebyscore([key, count, count + 120000], function() {});
          count += 120000;
      }   
  }); 

  client.exec(function(err, results) {
      if(err) { console.log(err);     }   
      else    { console.log(results); }
      client.quit();
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you use `multi`/`exec`.  The `multi` call returns an object that you must hold on to:

```
client  = redis.createClient(REDIS_SOCK);

client.keys(['*'], function(err, keys) {
  multi = client.multi();

  keys.forEach(function(key) {
      count = start;

      while(count <= end) {
          multi.zrangebyscore([key, count, count + 120000], function() {});
          count += 120000;
      }   
  }); 

  multi.exec(function(err, results) {
      if(err) { console.log(err);     }   
      else    { console.log(results); }
      client.quit();
  }); 
});
```

Since you can have many `multi`s active at a time, this is how the redis lib knows which one you're trying to exec.

Comment: i am using following code
`client.multi([    ["mget", "multifoo", "multibar", redis.print],    ["incr", "multifoo"],    ["incr", "multibar"]]).exec(function (err, replies) {    console.log(replies.toString());});`
and still i am getting the “EXEC without MULTI” error. Is there a possibility that redis lib can get confused even with this method about which multi to execute ?